# Avoid Quotation Marks without htmlspecialchars

Tags: javascript, php

I have below search.php file:

```
<?php
$q = $_GET["q"];
?>

<html>
...
<input id="inp" type="text">
...
...
<script>
// here i'm trying to avoid harmful user input with htmlspecialchars        
document.getElementById("inp").value = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($q); ?>"; 
</script>
...
</html>
```

When i request search.php?q=Adam (or anything A-Z, a-z) it's working normal. But when i search for " or \ input value differs from $_GET["q"] value.

But if i search for " it adds \, see below image.

[image]

All i need is set input value to $_GET["q"]. Is there any better solution for this?

Comment: `$q = htmlspecialchars($_GET["q"])`

Comment: @SagarV — How does using `htmlspecialchars` a second time help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> // here i'm trying to avoid harmful user input with htmlspecialchars        
> document.getElementById("inp").value = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($q); ?>";
> ```

You're generating **JavaScript**, not HTML.

(While it is embedded in an HTML document, a `<script>` element is defined as containing CDATA so the normal rules of HTML don't apply).

The appropriate tool to convert a PHP data structure or primitive to a JavaScript compatible format is `json_encode`.

```
document.getElementById("inp").value = <?php echo json_encode($q); ?>;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I replaced htmlspecialchars() with json_encode(). It's working normal with most of the characters. But when i search for " or / it's adding another \ before that character. For example, i search for "" and input value changes to \"\" which isn't nice.

Comment: @bored_lines — Sounds like you have Magic Quotes turned on. [Turn them off](http://php.net/security.magicquotes.disabling). Better yet: Upgrade PHP. Magic quotes were removed in PHP 5.4 which stopped getting security fixes in 2015.

Comment: my PHP version is 7.1.1, Also i run this: `if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) { echo "on";} else { echo "off"; }` and it returns off. I have tried php function addslashes($q); it also does the same thing.

Comment: Then you should not get the \ added.  I can't reproduce that problem.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It's my mistake, it the beginning of the code i declared $q = $_GET["q"]; but there was a line $q = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $q); This was the problem. Thank you for help!